# Azure Powershell New-AzADUser: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'MobilePhone'

Tags: azure, powershell

When I try to create a new user through the Azure portal powershell using the following command (replaced all values):

```
New-AzADUser -DisplayName "DisplayName" -MailNickname "email@gmail.com" -UserPrincipalName "UserPrincipalName" -Mail "mail" -MobilePhone "+31000000" -Department "Department"
```

I get the following error:

```
New-AzADUser: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'MobilePhone'.
```

But [reading the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azaduser?view=azps-9.1.0) does show support for the parameter 'MobilePhone'. And the same is true when doing 'Get-Help New-AzADUser'.

[image]

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this and how to resolve it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've tried to create a new user through the Azure portal PowerShell from my end and it works for me as shown below*:

```
connect-AzureAD
$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = "xxxxxxx"
$mobile = "+xxxx000000"
New-AzureADUser -DisplayName "xxxUser" -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -UserPrincipalName "<UserPrincipalName>" -AccountEnabled $true -MailNickName "demouser" -Mobile $mobile
```

Prior attempts resulted in the same problem for me.

So, ***I modified the parameter from
`-MobilePhone` to `-Mobile`  by referring*** [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0)

*Created a password file by referring `PSobject` from this [article](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/create-azure-ad-user-examples/):*

[image]

[image]

***User got created successfully in Azure AD:***

[image]

Comment: The issue for the command 'New-AzADUser' persists but this is a good workaround for my case - Thanks.